# How can I show a maintenance page when my web server is down or completely powered off?

Tags: webserver, maintenance-mode

I work for a company which has its own web server they are due to have a complete power blackout over the weekend, meaning their servers will be down.

Does anyone know a way we could present a down status on a maintenance page or some kind of redirect so we can at least inform our users that the site is down for maintenance and not just missing/broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is probably setting up a redirection to dummy server on your load balancer or border routers. If you have no such thing, then you can either try asking your provider about the options, or temporarily change the DNS record, provided that you reduce DNS cache timeouts before and after the change, so it takes effect immediately.

Comment: So far this seems to be the only solution, I'm going to leave this open for a bit before selecting it as an answer just in case some better idea comes along

Comment: One thing I'd add is to "reduce DNS cache timeouts" on your DNS server, you would shorten the TTL (Time To Live) for that record.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a server on another location and point their domains DNS record to that server during the blackout.

Comment: I would not advise that, since DNS is heavily cached, and so the customers might get "not available" site even hours after the're redirected back. Unless you make special provisions to reduce cache timeout values.

Comment: @che: is there another way? HTTP Redirects won't work (since the server is down) and I wouldn't advise doing this for a short maintenance break, but since it is 48 hours I see no other reasonable way of doing it, except having a diesel generator hooked up to the server and network equipment during the blackout.

Comment: Well, you can set up a redirect at your provider, or serve the pages from a lapton connected to car battery.

Comment: LOL, I like the image of the diesel generator powering the web site.  But this likely won't work.  It could power the company's internal not work, but depending on the scope of the outage, they may not be able to get to the Net because it impacts the service provider as well.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect has to be carried out by the web server.  No web server, no redirect.  What you can do is to get another web site by a web hosting company (which will not be subject to your blackout), and configure it to route requests from your main dns to the temp site with just a plain notice html page, then remove it once power is restored.  This can be done if you have the dns info from the primary site.  You could also mirror the site this way, and then shut down the mirror and no one will be the wiser.  Try http://siteground.com  I have used them for years.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a load balancer, see if it supports a "Sorry Server" page.  Most of them have this feature built in.